# Python Windows write HEX to BIN into file

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, binary, hex

I have the following script that keeps a binary file as HEX into a variable and dumps it as binary into a file, all work ok under Linux but fails under Windows and I don't know why:

```
import os, os.path
from ctypes import *
import sys, binascii

current_dir = r".\\"
startup = "4d5a90000300000004000000ffff0000b800000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" # snipped, too big to have it here

def DumpStartupFile():
        startupbin=binascii.unhexlify(startup)
        o=open(current_dir+"\\startup.exe","w")
        o.write(startupbin)

if os.path.isfile(current_dir+"\\startup.exe"):
        True
else:
        DumpStartupFile()
```

Any idea why it fails under Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always want to open a file in binary mode when writing binary data:

```
o=open(current_dir+"\\startup.exe","wb")
o.write(startupbin)
```

Especially on Windows, opening a file in text modus leads to newlines being translated into platform-native values on write, but that is not desirable behaviour for binary data.

From the [`open()` function documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> The default is to use text mode, which may convert `'\n'` characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading. Thus, when opening a binary file, you should append `'b'` to the *mode* value to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability. (Appending `'b'` is useful even on systems that don’t treat binary and text files differently, where it serves as documentation.)

Comment: Oops, I think you're right, under Linux doesn't fail without specifying binary mode, I think this is the problem, let me see.

Comment: @xtmtrx: On Linux, `\n` is the correct representation for a line break, so they are not translated there. :-)